# how can I write a constraints(x) in matlab 'fminsearch' like 'fmincon'

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

hi guys I have some problem

I coding some optimization one

4 variables   f(x1,x2,x3,x4)

so...I was using 'fmincon'...but it doesn't work very well

here is the Question

how can I write a constraints(x) in 'fminsearch'  like 'fmincon'

---------------constraints(x) form look like---------------------------

```
    function [C, Ceq] = constraints(x)

    B=1200;       
    N=1;          

    C(1)= 60-x(1) ;
    C(2)= 50-x(4) ;                                                 
    C(3)=-140+x(1)+x(2);                                   
    C(4)=-x(3)+x(4);                                       
    C(7)=x(3)-B*N;                                       
    C(5)=-x(2);                                          
    C(6)= x(1)*B + x(4)*x(2)*N + (x(3)-x(4))*x(2)/2*N -107000; 

    Ceq=[];

    end
```

---

cruel life xoxo

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `fminsearch` is for unconstrained problems.

However, you can choose a different `fmincon` algorithm:

- 'interior-point' (default)
- 'trust-region-reflective'
- 'sqp'
- 'sqp-legacy'
- 'active-set'

See [fmincon Algorithms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-the-algorithm.html). Use `optimoptions` to set the Algorithm option at the command line.